# Using existing library in my react code throws support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled

Tags: javascript, babeljs

While using existing library in my react application throws
**

```
syntaxerror: then library path: support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled.
Add @babel/preset-react to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

**

I tried adding @babel/preset-react in my react code babel.config.js but it is not working.

Comment: what library are you referring to?

Comment: It is internal library build with react, redux and rollup.js

Comment: Is there any way I could change my code to overcome this issue

Comment: Did you _install_ babel/preset-react or just add the words to the config?

Comment: I installed in devdependencies